# php redirecting to a blank page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a little problem. 
I have a website where I have a contact form. I have a form.php file which makes it work, and in this file I have echo calling for a js function which makes a popup window telling you "thank you for submitting" instead of taking me to another page with this message. The problem is when I click OK on this popup window, it redirects to an empty page form.php.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n\n Message: $message";
$recipient = "mailing@tpczech.com";
$subject = "Contact Form TP Czech";  //This is the email subject in " "
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";



mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo '<script>popUp()</script>';


?>
```

Comment: What did you expect. You are submitting to form.php and in there displaying a popup. When you click the pop up you are still in form.php, which is as you say empty.

Comment: You're not defining `popUp()` anywhere here. Remember that the form request triggers a new page request. None of the previous HTML or JavaScript will be there once redirected.

Comment: why don't you alert the message. like,
`if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){echo "<script>alert('form sent')</script>"}else{echo "<script>alert('form not sent');</script>"}`

Answer (score 1):

To show the content inside the pop you need to have the code like this.

```
 if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
        echo '<script>
      var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>Message sent!</p>");</script>';
      }else{
        echo '<script>
      var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>Message Not sent!</p>");</script>';
      }
```

The popup window can be called by using [open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) Method.
**Advance Integration:**
You can also close the open window after a time period using [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function and [close()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp) function.

```
//This will close the popup window after 10 sec.
    setTimeout(function(){
       myWindow.close(); 
    }, 10000);
```